# Can I use a charger with different current than the original?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power

I have no idea about electricity so I don't know what any of this means. On the plug of my original charger, the numbers are 5A/250~ and on the cable that connects to the power supply 'brick', it says 2.5A 250V~.
On the brick it says
INPUT 100-240V 1.16A, 50.60Hz
OUTPUT 15V = 2.58A, 5.1V = 1A

Now I've got this new charger, and on the plug the numbers are 13A/250, on the cable that connects to the brick 2.5A, 250V~, and on the brick  itself
INPUT 100v-240v 50/60Hz
OUTPUT 15V - 2.58A, 5V-1.5A

I don't know how to check what my laptop requires, it's Microsoft Surface Laptop 2 from 2018, Model 1769

Can I use this replacemnt adapter?

Comment: You'll definitely need to find out the requirements of your laptop, that's the part that matters most. Your new power-adapter's output voltage will need to match that of your laptop, and its input voltage will need to match whatever your outlets are (though they are often universal and will work with 110-240V). The current will need to be *at least* what your laptop needs. If your laptop says 2.5A, then you'll need at least that on the output of the adapter. However, laptops and their power-adapters usually work with Watts, which again, you'll need to find one with a *minimum* of that.

Comment: You should be able to find the Surface's power requirements by looking at the bottom. It should be printed on a sticker there.

Comment: there is neither a sticker at the bottom, nor I recall it being there ever, any other way I can check what are the requirements?

Comment: Surface connectors are proprietary and specific to Surface devices. If the connector is the same then it is down to the 15V - 2.58A which is the same for both so it should be fine. The only question is whether the alternative adaptor is from a reputable seller or manufacturer and whether you trust it enough to plug it in.

Comment: Eh, not really, I suppose I will have to pay that £66 for an actual replacement, I don't won't to risk it